# GWT styling my image in Java makes my page not load

Tags: java, css, gwt

So I am adding a shopping cart to my GWT webpage, I would like to add a cart image to this shopping cart. I have set up my image as follows.

**General Icon Interface**

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;

public interface GeneralIcons extends ClientBundle { 

    public static final GeneralIcons INSTANCE = GWT.create(GeneralIcons.class);

    @Source("cart_red.png")
    ImageResource cartRed();
}
```

**Class Using Image**

```
...
Image shoppingCartImage = new Image(GeneralIcons.INSTANCE.cartRed()); 
...
```

If I stop right here than everything works properly, and my image shows up. But I would like to style my image, for instance I want to put some padding around the edges of my image so I try

```
...
Image shoppingCartImage = new Image(GeneralIcons.INSTANCE.cartRed());
shoppingCartImage.getElement().addClassName(style.padding());
...
```

When I do this and recompile, nothing shows up at all on my page, just a straight white background. Any Idea what I did wrong?

**Edit**

So in my console I found

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'padding' of null
```

I am sure I have setup my style correctly (using UiBinder) as I have done this before and it is working correctly in other classes.

Comment: What browser are you using? Share complete testable code such as CSS, style object. how are you adding it in the page.

Comment: chrome, will check on FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your style to Image, not its element:

```
shoppingCartImage.addStyleName(style.padding());
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue, I did however find the console which gave me a hint, check the edit to the post

Answer (score 0):

Ahh so remember when I was so sure I setup my style correctly? Yeah that was wrong. I had the following code in my class

```
interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
    String padding();
}

MyStyle style;
```

Well it needed to be

```
interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
    String padding();
}

@UiField
MyStyle style;
```

Thanks everyone!